# Ubuntu Java jdk 8 Installation Issue. installed RPM of java8 after installed found openjkd 11

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Hie, I am confused where I am messed up.

I have downloaded JDK and JRE rpm files from the Oracle download page. I am using a 64-bit Linux machine ubuntu 18.04 os.

here the file I have downloaded
[image]

I used alien to convert into .deb files and then I have used dpkg to install deb.

I have installed JRE 1.8 . and I have installed maven via command line. but after install, I found this surprisingly

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the paths where Oracle packages with Java were installed, you can use `update-alternatives` to choose which Java you want to use. For example, in my case:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51/bin/javaws" 1
```

and in the end:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose the the number of your Oracle Java installation.

Comment: thanks, mate00. there was an installation problem with oracle rpm files. manually downloading and extracting tar and setting alternative worked.

Comment: Super, I'm glad. :) Is it ok if you upvote my answer?